# Getting an attribute in velocity file which is set in java file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have set attribute in controller as:

```
request.setAttribute("imageMap", s);
```

`s` is defined as:

```
String s = ChartUtilities.getImageMap("imageMap", info);
```

I am accessing imageMap in vm file as `$imageMap` but I'm not getting desired result. Please tell me where I'm going wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Show the velocity template portion you are using `$imageMap`.

Comment: Are you using Spring framework or other ?

Comment: yes i am using spring framework

Comment: How you sending this `imageMap` to velocity template?Can you post that code and your velocity template code too?